# Apache Solr word level ngram

Tags: solr, lucene, n-gram

I have to configure Solr for word level ngram (uni, bi and trigram). For example, if input (Index or query) is as follows:

"Welcome to Apache Solr"
It should be tokenized as

```
Unigram: "Welcome", "to", "Apache", "Solr"
Bigram: "Welcome to", "to Apache", "Apache Solr"
Trigram: "Welcome to Apache", "to Apache Solr"
```

How should I get this from Solr. I have consulted default guide of Solr, I have not find word level [tokenizer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/tokenizers.html).

Comment: I updated the answer...Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Shingle Filter here.

This filter constructs shingles, which are token n-grams, from the token stream. It combines runs of tokens into a single token.

```
<analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

In: `"To be, or what?"`

Tokenizer to Filter: `"To"(1), "be"(2), "or"(3), "what"(4)`

Out: `"To"(1), "To be"(1), "be"(2), "be or"(2), "or"(3), "or what"(3), "what"(4)`

you use the below property as well.

`maxShingleSize :` (integer, must be >= minShingleSize, default 2) The maximum number of tokens per shingle.

I tried for the text you requested.

Here is the fieldtype applied.

```
<fieldType name="text_tokens" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="4" outputUnigrams="true"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

The expected output is :

```
Unigram: "Welcome", "to", "Apache", "Solr"
Bigram: "Welcome to", "to Apache", "Apache Solr"
Trigram: "Welcome to Apache", "to Apache Solr"
```

The output given after applying the above fieldtype is :
[image: Solr Analysis Page]

Here is covers all the expected tokens like

```
unigram : Welcome, to , Apache , Solr
bigram : Welcome to , to Apache, Apache Solr 
trigram : Welcome to Apache , to Apache Solr
```

For more details please refer the below link.
[Shingle Filter Example](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html)